# Rewriting all requests to subfolder without changing url, and forcing url if folder exists?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am rewriting all requests to a folder named public **without** changing the url with .htaccess in my root directory. Now if I go to http://sitename.com/js then it redirects to http://sitename.com/public/js. But if I go to http://sitename.com/js/ then it works fine, without changing the url. Could someone explain why and help me with this?

.htaccess in **root** directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to `mod_dir` which runs after `mod_rewrite` and adds a trailing slash.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/(css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=401]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1/ !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*?)/?$ public/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -d [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).+?)/?$ public/$1/ [L,NC]
```

Comment: Works great, but would if say if they go to http://sitename.com/public/js or http://sitename.com/public/css and I want to show a 401 error, could I do that?